# git how to undo a specific commit

Tags: git

I am fairly new to git and I am struggling with the below scenario. I will detail my scenario with a local repo only, the real life one is with many developers pushing / pulling modifications from/to other developers before working on a new branch.

First I create a new repo with an initial file:

```
cloudshell:~ $ mkdir test-git2
cloudshell:~ $ cd test-git2/
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/denis/test-git2/.git/
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ echo "first commit" > b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git add b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) a21ac9b] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ cat b
first commit
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $
```

A first developer modifies this file through a branch:

```
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ echo "branch1" >> b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git add b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git commit -m "branch1"
[branch1 571d6fe] branch1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git status
On branch branch1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ cat b
first commit
branch1
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $
```

After that, a second developer implements something else on this file:

```
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git checkout -b branch2
Switched to a new branch 'branch2'
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ echo "branch2" >> b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git add b
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git commit -m "branch2"
[branch2 9eb8609] branch2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git status
On branch branch2nothing to commit, working tree clean
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ cat b
first commit
branch1
branch2
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ git branch
  branch1
* branch2
  master
cloudshell:~/test-git2
```

Later on, for any reason, we are asked to remove the modifications made in "branch1" and here is where I am stuck:

- I could easily git revert HEAD to revert the last commit but this is not what I want
- I could "go back in time" and git revert HEAD~2 which indeed revert my "branch1" modifications but this also revert the "branch2" modifications which I want to keep. I then tried to cherry-pick the branch 2 commit to re-apply it but It ended with this in my file (I got the same result with git revert ):

```
   
cloudshell:~/test-git2 $ cat b
    first commit
    >>>>>> cd08a37... file a updated branch 2
    cloudshell:~/test-git $
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I could "go back in time" and git revert HEAD~2 which indeed revert my "branch1" modifications but this also revert the "branch2" modifications which I want to keep

Simply switch ([`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) if you have Git 2.23+) back to `branch1`, revert HEAD there, then merge `branch1` to `branch2`.

Or, if there is only one developer to `branch2`, and `branch2` was not pushed yet, you can (after the revert done on `branch1`) do a `git switch branch2` and `git rebase branch1` (rebase `branch2` on top of `branch1`)

> Also, branches are pushed as 1 developer works on `branch1` and another one on `branch2` so we have to push and pull to get the other one branch.

```
# as developer1
git checkout branch1
git revert HEAD
git push

# as developer2
git checkout branch2
git merge branch1
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, I have git 2.12.2 so I don't have git switch. Also, branches are pushed as 1 developer works on branch1 and another one on branch2 so we have to push and pull to get the other one branch.

Comment: Could you please detail the commands that would work for my scenario ? I am a bit lost in all of this. Thanks,

Comment: @FredDENIS Sure. I have edited the answer to add the commands.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I tried this and I got some conflicts:
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ cat b
first commit
branch1
branch2
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ git checkout branch1
Switched to branch 'branch1'
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ git revert HEAD
[branch1 07ca123] Revert "branch1"
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ cat b
first commit
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ git checkout branch2
Switched to branch 'branch2'

Comment: cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ git merge branch1
Auto-merging b
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in b
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $ cat b
first commit
<<<<<<< HEAD
branch1
branch2
=======
>>>>>>> branch1
cloudshell:~/test-git3 $

Comment: @FredDENIS Sure, that is expected: concurrent modification between branches. Resolve the conflict (https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line) and complete the merge. By resolving the conflict, you will be able to keep your branch2 modification while dropping out branch1 modifications.

Comment: Thanks. I found (and tried) git mergetool for this, it is indeed manual (and to be honnest I would have expected something more automatic as git knows exactly what has been added and removed in a commit and then by a branch) but seems to be a good tool for this. Thanks again !

Comment: @FredDENIS Great (I mentioned mergetool before indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a6309%20mergetool)